# GraphQL + Apollo + Angular how to pass multiple where conditions into Query?

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo-client

I am trying to pass several values of variables into where part of the GraphQL Query but I'm facing the problem that not all variables have values and default values like null are not accepted by the GraphQL endpoint.

I think that I need to pass only variables that do have non-null values and from these non-null values create the **where condition**. I tried to find some examples but the examples I found contains only the simple where condition above one attribute only.

I found this example too: https://www.howtographql.com/typescript-apollo/8-filtering-pagination-and-sorting/

But it seems to be a pretty awful and not simple implementation.

Could someone tell me what pattern should I use to achieve dynamic filtering for more fields at the same time?

Thanks for any advice.

**Query where i Would like to use more condtitions:**

```
export const GET_SCENE_EVENTS_BY_PAGINATION_FILTER = gql`
    query queryEvents($sceneId: Int!,  $numberOfRows: Int!, $eventTypeId: Byte!, $from: DateTime!, $to: DateTime!) {
        queryEvents(
            sceneId: $sceneId
            where: { and: [{ dateTime: { gte: $from } },{ dateTime: { lte: $to } }, { eventTypeId: { eq: $eventTypeId }}] }
            # how many events from beggining of list
            first: $numberOfRows
            order: [{ dateTime: DESC }]
        )
        {${SCENE_EVENT_RESPONSE_STRUCT}}
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
query queryEvents($sceneId: Int!,  $numberOfRows: Int!, $whereClause: QueryEventInput!) {
    queryEvents(
        sceneId: $sceneId
        where: $whereClause
        # how many events from beggining of list
        first: $numberOfRows
        order: [{ dateTime: DESC }]
    )
    {${SCENE_EVENT_RESPONSE_STRUCT}}
}
```

You don't want variables that are the individual elements of your where clause. You want a single variable that is the *entire* where clause. Check the input type of `where`, and that's what you will replace what I called `QueryEventInput`.